# Is there a comparison chart of privileges between Office 365 tenant admin, Sharepoint admin , site collection admin and site owner?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-administration, sharepoint-admin-center

Is there a comparison chart of privilages between Office 365 tenant admin, Sharepoint admin , site collection admin and site owner ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check as follows:

[image]

In general, Global admin> SharePoint admin> Site collection admin>Site Owner.

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/about-admin-roles?view=o365-worldwide

[https://collabshow.com/2011/12/21/sharepoint-site-collection-administrator-vs-site-owner/#:~:text=The%20site%20owner%20is%20the,across%20all%20content%20and%20galleries](https://collabshow.com/2011/12/21/sharepoint-site-collection-administrator-vs-site-owner/#:%7E:text=The%20site%20owner%20is%20the,across%20all%20content%20and%20galleries).

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/office-365-sharepoint-online-site-collection-administrators/